# Suppose $2y+3x=3y-4x$, and $x$ and $y$ are not both zero. Prove that $y$ does not equal $0$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I was wondering if my explanation makes sense. I solved the equations each if one or the other was $0$ like the following:

$2y+3(0) = 3y-4(0) \implies 0=y$, meaning both $y$ and $x$ equal zero to make the statement correct.

$2(0)+3x = 3(0)-4x \implies 0=x$, meaning both $x$ and $y$ equal zero to make the statement correct.

Therefore, $y\neq 0$ because if one of them were to be zero, the other one has to be zero for the statement to be true.

Comment: Please use mathjax. Google, "math stackexchange mathjax tutorial"

Comment: Here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only needed that last equation to prove it. You did a proof by contradiction where you assumed the opposite of the conjecture and found a contradiction. In this case, it asks for you to prove $y\neq 0$, so for a proof by contradiction you will assume that $y=0$. Your second equation already does that and finds that $x=0$, but you know that both $x$ and $y$ cannot be zero. You have found a contradiction and are done. Your first equation is unnecessary for this problem because you have already solved it.